# How to handle external API rate limits?

Tags: laravel, api, vimeo-api, rate-limiting

When using services such as **Twitter** or **Vimeo**  they use API rate limit for each request that happen to there API and they will return ( in the response's headers ) something like this:

X-RateLimit-Limit
X-RateLimit-Remaining
X-RateLimit-Reset

For example, In my app I will use **Vimeo API** for alot of things.. like:

- Upload a video
- Edit a video
- Get a video

For each request to  **Vimeo API**  I have to check if **X-RateLimit-Remaining** value is > 0 to **continue** or return **error** if the rate limit has been exceeded. ( [Vimeo API rate limit](https://developer.vimeo.com/guidelines/rate-limiting) ).

---

#### Is there a good practice to handle external API rate limit?

#### What is the best place to store these values, so that I can retrieve them when needed?

**Note**: Vimeo API doesn't just return an error when rate limit has been reached, It will banned my app when I exceed that limit as the docs says. So I need to store them some where.  ( [#Vimeo API rate limit](https://developer.vimeo.com/guidelines/rate-limiting) ).

Comment: I think since the API return these values in the header then you can just check it each time. This means you don't need to store them. Let me know if I may have misunderstood your question. I think even github api for example allows you to check your limit by sending a request: see: https://developer.github.com/v3/rate_limit/

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin

Vimeo API doesn't just return an error when rate limit has been reached, It will banned my app when I exceed that limit as the docs says. So I need to store them some where. https://developer.vimeo.com/guidelines/rate-limiting

I have updated my question.

Comment: Laravel provide a way with the throttling middleware https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-6-dynamic-rate-limiting

Comment: @cbaconnier this is for internal API requests. I am using external API.

Comment: I think you can use cache, session, or db to update the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should chache the values locally, depending on your cache driver, which can be redis, memcached, etc...

Read more here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/cache

I'd suggest you to create a class to manage the cached values, updating/creating them from the APIs when needed. This class could be a dependency of the class which actually contains the logic to call the external APIs.

Comment: Yes, It seems redis is the way to go.. since Database would effect the performance because I will be using these values a lot. thank you.

Just out of curiosity, did you happen to work with such a case before?